# IE not allowing tbody height to be set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following which is a mostly css scrollable table. Works great in Chrome and Firefox, but it will not set the height of the tbody element in IE 9. any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/BvPNK/3/

```
function scrollify(table,height){

   table.find('thead').addClass('fixed_header');
   table.find('tbody').addClass('scroll_content').height(height);
   $('<div/>').addClass('table_wrap').appendTo(table.parent()).append(table);

}
```

css

```
.fixed_header th,tbody.scroll_content td{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   width:3em;/*this is dynamically set in full function*/
}
.table_wrap{
    float:left;
}
.fixed_header tr{
     position:relative;

}
.scroll_content{
    display:block;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:show;
}
```

Comment: Table cells with `float` on them seem very strange to me. Are you sure tables is what you need?

Comment: I need a fixed header and a scrollable content area, the float is to collapse the table_wrap to the right size.

Comment: You have a js error - `'th_widths' is undefined`

Comment: sorry that was the wrong fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BvPNK/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that it is simply an issue with IE not respecting tbody (or table for that matter) `height` css property. I could not for the life of me style the height for table or tbody elements in IE. You can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4457290/550309), that the last comment mentions it does not work for IE.

Answer (score 1):

to set the css height of ein element you should use the css-function. the height function should be used to do mathematical stuff.

you did that correct in your second fiddle. if you do this, you should call your function with a string as param, and your unit:

```
scrollify($('table'), "300px");
```

edit: there really seems to be an issue with height and ie9. innerHeight though should work.

i updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BvPNK/10/

Comment: Thanks, though this still fails to change the height of the tbody element in IE.

Comment: it still didn't run for me in ie9