# Why is the overflow not working here?

Tags: css

This is my css; I need this to have s scroll or auto overflow for all its content. I can't understand why it is not showing up.

```
.holder{
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 2.5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    background-image:url("images\\tile2.png");
    background-repeat:repeat;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: please add relating HTML markup to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: table;` and you will see the scrollbar.

Live Example: http://jsbin.com/aloler/1/edit

Here's your code with `display: table;` removed: http://jsbin.com/aloler/2/

Comment: This worked thanks! Does the overflow never work in the table display or is it a combination of bad decisions that led to this?

Comment: @VladOtrocol, not sure. `display: table;` treats the element as a `<table>`. Searching around it looks like getting scrollbars to work with tables requires some workarounds. I couldn't find an exact reason why these two are not compatible.

Comment: @VladOtrocol, there's some good info. here (including workarounds) about tables and overflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4457290/1085891