# How to display large matrix in pandas with scroll bars in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have written about 100 lines of code in a Jupyter Notebook cell, and in the middle of the code, I have something like this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
x = np.random.rand(1000,3)
display(pd.DataFrame(x))
```

It shows me the entire table, but I was wondering if there is an option in Pandas to limit the vertical size of the output table & add a vertical scroll bar to allow better viewing. I mean, a separate vertical scroll bar than the cell output scroll bar (which I have toggled off by the way).

From what I understand, one option is to use Plotly table visualization as explained in [this](https://plotly.com/python/table/), but I wanted to avoid that if possible & use a more native solution because with plotly / Dash, the table text is not selectable anymore (Not sure haven't tested it yet though).

Comment: Does this thread help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724327/pandas-dataframe-table-vertical-scrollbars (particularly the updated part of the selected answer).

Comment: @fhorrobin yes that was very helpful! I added the answer to the question text.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution from [Pandas DataFrame Table Vertical Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724327/pandas-dataframe-table-vertical-scrollbars). Add this:

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Puts the scrollbar next to the DataFrame
display(
    HTML(
        "<div style='height: 200px; overflow: auto; width: fit-content'>" +
        df1.to_html() +
        "</div>"
    )
)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71084687/revisions) to the question [How to display large matrix in pandas with scroll bars in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71084687/how-to-display-large-matrix-in-pandas-with-scroll-bars-in-jupyter-notebook) by the OP [dani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14070764/dani) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Comment: This is great, thank you. Any idea if it can be made faster for larger DataFrames?

Answer (score 0):

I created this function that I always copy paste on any of my notebook

```
def print_df(df, head=10):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
        display(df.head(head))
```

and I just need to call `print_df(df)` to check some sample data