# Pandas Dataframe Table Vertical Scrollbars in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a large (vertically) pandas Dataframe that I would like to display as a nice table with (vertical) scrollbars in a `jupyter notebook` in `vs code`.

I have come across post that addresses the solution, but it is 5 years old, so was wondering if there is now a better method. Here is the post:
[Pandas DataFrame Table Vertical Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724327/pandas-dataframe-table-vertical-scrollbars)

Right now I use the following to see all the data:

```py
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
```

But this shows **all** the rows which becomes problematic when, say >100 rows.

Just to be clear, i am looking for a scroll bar (as in the image):
[image]

Comment: Try: pd.options.display.max_rows = 100

Comment: just tried, but this does not have any effect.  i am looking for some way of getting the `vertical` scroll bar...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a solution for plain Jupyter, but for the successor [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) it's quite easy, not just for DataFrames but for all outputs.

It looks like this:

[image: Output of pd.DataFrame(range(100)) with scrolling output enabled]

To enable this view you have to set `pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)` and then you have to make a right-click on the blue column and choose *Enable Scrolling for Outputs*:

[image: Right click menu showing the "Enable Scrolling for Outputs" option]

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically enable scrolling for outputs?  i.e., call it from the code rather than forcing user to click it.

Comment: @LogZ If there is, I would appreciate knowing it as well. But I did not see something like this yet.